# How do I use ASP.NET Web Forms in MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

Currently I'm rewriting an application to use **ASP.NET MVC4**.
I'm using C# with **razor views**.
I have some legacy Web Forms pages that I'd like to include unmodified in my application.
I'd like them to appear seamlessly with in my `_Layout`.
Is there a way I can render a Web Forms page within an MVC Layout that will still allow things like post backs to work?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at some of the information here:

[Mixing Razor Views and WebForms Master Pages with ASP.NET MVC 3](http://bit.ly/eR4Eue)

[Integrating ASP.NET MVC 3 into existing upgraded ASP.NET 4 Web Forms applications](http://bit.ly/fPQcb8)

Comment: I've looked and there's a lot of information about how to have WebForms exist next to MVC but nothing on how to have both in the same page, or if it's even possible.

Comment: Really what I need is some way to use the _Layout I want as a master page for the web forms but it appears that's not possible. So iframes it is...